# Calling a secured REST api from Javascript without user login screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth, azure-active-directory

How would you call the secured REST api from the Javascript script application that doesn't have the login?

I have a Javascript application (React) that doesn't have a user login. It needs to call some REST api services that uses Oauth (Azure Ad -
 WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication).

Those REST services have CORS enabled.

I also registered my web application in Azure Ad.

The issue is that the javascript application needs to call https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenantId}}/oauth2/token to get the access token. I found no way to enable the CORS for that URL. My JS application doens't have any login so I can't show the login screen in popup or use adal js.

The solution that I come up with is that I put my Javascript application in NodeJS (Express). The JS call the NodeJS that calls the login.microsoftonline.com to get the token and pass it when calling other secured REST services.

It works great but I think there might be some security issues around that.

Is there any better way to design this kind of application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is the proper approach. It keeps all the Oauth tokens secure on your server without having to expose them client side.

That is the main reason most Oauth2 API's don't implement CORS