# create-react-app + nodejs (express) server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app

I am using NodeJs + React in my application. I am using express in NodeJs. I created my sample app using 'create-react-app' npm.

I used NodeJs for calling the oauth token from react app. I mentioned this approach in this post [Calling a secured REST api from Javascript without user login screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48053565/calling-a-secured-rest-api-from-javascript-without-user-login-screen) .

I added this command below to start the NodeJs together with my react app. It works.

```
"scripts": {
  "node": "react-scripts-ts build & node server"
}
```

The issue is that I don't get the real time tracking feature that comes with 'create-react-app' because I am not starting the webpack-dev-server. If I made some changes, I have to run 'yarn node' to recomple and start the node js server.

My question is how to start the nodejs express without losing the 'create-react-app''s live tracking feature.

If I need to eject the 'create-react-app' and customize the script, I am fine as long as I got the following feature.

- start nodejs express - api
- load my react-app
- if there is any change in my react or nodejs express file, it should auto-reload.

Feel free to let me know if you have any question.

Thanks,

Comment: You don't get hot reloading on production build (AFAIK). When you run your `node` script, that's what is getting done. Run the dev server for HMR. Generally, that is `npm start`   See https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/38#issuecomment-100720502

Comment: Thanks Dane. I will look at it. I thnk I need to eject the 'create-react-app' first.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48851722/82686 - How to use Create React App with Node.js backend (without ejecting)

Answer (score 13):

There's an excellent tutorial on a good way to handle this setup: https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/using-create-react-app-with-a-server/

To summarize: you can write your node+express server in whatever way you're accustomed to - we'll say this lives in a directory called `project` - then *nest within it* a frontend directory created using create-react-app, e.g. `project/client`.

When you're developing, you'll actually run two servers: the backend server (`npm start`) and the webpack-dev-server that comes with your nested create-react-app (`cd client && npm start`).  In your browser, you'll navigate to the url being served by webpack-dev-server (localhost:3000 by default).

In production, you don't need to run two servers.  You'll bundle your frontend (`cd client && npm run build`), then your backend server just needs to serve the bundle, for example via express's static middleware:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static('client/build'))
}
```

I skipped over a few details, so do check out the tutorial I linked if this setup sounds right for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd run separately nodejs server with nodemon (https://nodemon.io/) and create react app. I'd say, make server side UI-agnostic.

Just curious, why do you need to reload UI after server changes? You can complete server side, write unit/integration tests and then write UI.

Feel free to ask any questions, will try to help

Comment: Thanks. Let's say I am developing the app on my machine. So, create-react-app comes with 'yarn start' which has reloaded the app when I made some changes in my react app. but I need to call the nodejs api to get the auth token before calling another API from my react app. I want to reload the website if there is any change in either node js or react app.